# How to store only on external storage storage/sdcard0/?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I want to store data on external storage and Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns /storage/emulated/0/
path and and when i store data on that directory it store data on storage/sdcard0/... and on /storage/emulated/0/

I need to store a great numbers of images on external storage
How could i implement that?How could i get path on external storage?

Comment: Well that is the path to external storage. Doesn't the function name say as much?

Answer (score 1):

> How could I get path on external storage?

`/storage/emulated/0/` and `storage/sdcard0/` is basically the same, this is just an alias. On devices like the Nexus 5 and any other device that doesn't have a physical SD card, "external storage" means the device built-in storage which emulates an SD card. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` will point to this location so you are good to go using this method.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29):

> Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory
>   can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that
>   can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across
>   all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is
>   an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a
>   device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be
>   mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all find of path of external storage

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + directoryName;
```

then you can write whatever content you want to the file as follows:

```
File file = new File(path, fileName);
        BufferedWriter br;
        try {
            br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            br.write(content);
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: This does not address the question asked, which is actually a simple misunderstanding.